# Aligning two images and text in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to align two pictures and text. When the first picture is commented out, the text and the second picture are aligned in the middle of a card. But the first picture is always aligned to bottom of the card. I tried all layout properties so far without luck.

See the screenshot for example. I do not understand why the circle is bigger than OK button because when I open these files they have the same dimensions. Where is the issue? I want to use `LinearLayout` as the simplest layout manager available.

[image]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/badge_type"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_gold_circle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/badge_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/badge_title_KNIGHT"
        style="@style/PlayRecordHeader"
         />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/badge_status"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_correct"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Update** with `layout_gravity="center_vertical"`

[image]

Comment: Add to `LinearLayout`  `android:gravity="center_vertical"`

Comment: Hmm, both question and accepted answer downvoted :-/ I hate anonymous downvotes without clear reason.

Comment: @LeosLiterak you know what, the conversation we're having is pointless, I gave you a thorough explanation of your "problem" but apparently you didn't understand it at all, and you rewarded a person that answered you after me. Now the whole conversation it's just heading in the "negative" direction. It's pointless. Let me just clear all traces of me being here. Like I never been here. Cheers.

Comment: @BartekLipinski I put the upvote elsewhere. Thank you for your help. And sorry that I did not understand that your text comment about distributing weight means the same like Lino's attribute.

Comment: @BartekLipinski "I put the upvote elsewhere" => " I upvoted you elsewhere"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to keep

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

and remove

```
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
```

in the LinearLayout